# FPDF: MULTICELL Generation of Report

Tags: php, arrays, pdf, pdo, fpdf

[Here is the image of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ekvry.png)
I have a problem on how to escape repeating data using multi-cell. I want to distinct the name and business name. Please help me

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tres','root','');
$pdf->SetWidths(Array(15,80,65,35,20,30,75,25));
$pdf->SetTextColor(0,0,0);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',9);
$tawen=$_POST['tawen'];

$stmt = $db->query("select * from tblbusper where year='$tawen' and status!='retired' order by lastna asc");
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
    $bp =$row->bpno;
    $stmts = $db->query("select * from tblgencol where bpno='$bp' and category='Business Permit'");
    while($rows = $stmts->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
        $rows->note;

        $pdf->Row(Array('',$row->lastna.', '.$row->firstna.' '.$row->surna,$row->busname,$row->busadd,'',$row->dateapp,
        $rows->note,$row->basinfo));
    }
}
```

Comment: So are you having problems escaping the data or is your problem that you only want unique data? The unique problem can be probably be solved by adding `distinct` and `group by ` to your queries.

Comment: For example: One person has many Business how can i escape the repeating data for the name and business name

Comment: or how can i store all the line of business of same person in one cell. Teach me